# Is it possible to send "all other" domains through to a single IP in bind?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

What I am looking to do, is exactly what the subject line reads .. Push all sites without a master record through to a specific IP address -- For example I have the following:

BIND SERVER(s) `ns1.mydnsserver.com`, `ns2.mydnsserver.com`

Next I have a list of sites (All with `ns1(2).mydnsserver.com` as their nameserver):

```
site1.com
site2.com
site3.com
site4.com
site5.com
```

I have master zone files that send `site1.com` and `site2.com` to go to IP addresses `*.*.*.2`, and `*.*.*.3` respectively  ---- I want **all others** to go to `*.*.*.4`  --- Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure this about what you want but... You might want to configure/setup a wildcard, any domain that is pointing to your name servers will resolve on your server

Comment: You can't defer these answers to another server in such a way that the authoritative answer flag on the reply will be passed through. All you can do is setup recursion against them, which not considered a best practice among DNS admins. Were you trying to do the former or the latter?

Comment: Basically I have, say, 100 domains that need to go to `.*.*.*3` -- Am am wondering if there is a way to just have a "default" push them to `.3.` (where they have Domain Aliases) without having to create a Master Record for every `site.com`

Comment: The common solution is to share the same zone file among all the similarly templated zones. One master definition for each, all sharing the same zone file.